# Open Specific sheets accord to cell values VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to protect my workbook by setting different passwords to open specific sheets.
I want to set a condition according to a cell value (on range B2 of each sheet).
So for example I have 3 passwords to open different sheets :

if passord= 123 and if range(B2) of each sheet eqauls to "xxx" then open all sheets where Range(B2)= "xxx"

if passord= 456 and if range(B2) of each sheet eqauls to "yyy" then open all sheets where Range(B2)= "yyy"

if passord= 789 and if range(B2) of each sheet eqauls to "zzz" then open all sheets where Range(B2)= "zzz"

I wrote this piece of code that helps me to open all sheets by setting a unic passwocde:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Open all sheets for admin
If Me.TextBox1.Value = "MC" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
    Me.Hide
    
Else
'Open all sheets where range(B2) = Planification et maintennace"
If Me.TextBox1.Value = "MC1" Then
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Range(B2).Value = "Planification et maintenance" Then
    ws.Visible = True
    End If
Next

'Open all sheets where range(B2) = Pole Essais"
If Me.TextBox1.Value = "MC2" Then
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Range(B2).Value = "Pole Essais" Then
    ws.Visible = True
    End If
Next

Else
MsgBox ("veuillez entrer un mot de passe valide !")
Unload Me

End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

This code is doing nothing, how can I improve it to make it work ?
Thank you

Comment: Replace `Range(B2)` with `Range("B2")`. Why are all your `End If` at the end? Also, unrelated to your problem but please consider using `Select Case` instead of using several times the `If` condition.

Comment: @romulax14 I made the changes but still cant open the desired sheets,

Comment: I made an answer with your code corrected, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.
First, you wrote `Range(B2)` instead of `Range("B2")`.
Then all of your `End If` are at the end, they shouldn't.
In this situation, you should `Select Case` instead of `If`
Also, when looping with a `For Each ws In ...`, the `Next` after the `For` must be written like `Next ws`, to tell excel to go to the next one.

I corrected your code, with proper indentation:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Select Case Me.TextBox1.Value
        Case "MC"
            ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = True
            Me.Hide
        Case "MC1"
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.Range("B2").Value = "Planification et maintenance" Then
                    ws.Visible = True
                End If
            Next ws
        Case "MC2"
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.Range("B2").Value = "Pole Essais" Then
                    ws.Visible = True
                End If
            Next ws
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("veuillez entrer un mot de passe valide !")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It's working when I want to open all sheets, but not  when I want to open sheest where I set the conditions.

Comment: My bad, i wrote just `Next` instead of `Next ws` at the end of each `For`, I edited my answer, please try again and let me know

Comment: We are writing e.g. `Next ws` only for readability, it is not necessary, just `Next` is fine and therefore not an issue.

Comment: Next or Next ws is the same thing, still not working

Comment: @IMP_Te: Try adding into the If statements after `ws.Visible = True` the following: `Else: ws.Visible = False`.

Comment: Got an error: The 'Visible' method of the '_Worksheet' object has failed

Comment: @VBasic2008 I didn't know!

Comment: @IMP_Te I just tried my code above and it works, when I enter MC1 it unhides the sheet with written "Planification et maintenance", and same for the other one when I enter MC2. Please make sure that you didn't make any typo in your cells, like for example if you wrole "pôle" instead of pole (I'm french too), and check if the values are in B2 or not B1 or something else. Finally, be aware that `ws.Visible = True` only unhides the sheet on the sheets list, it doesn't open it on screen. If you want to open it, write `ws.Activate` instead

Comment: My bad you were right, the values were in B1 not B2, sorry I should have been more carefull, Thank you very much now it's working